# How to disable swipe down for Notification Center in apps on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

When I’m playing games on my iPhone and I try to do some action on the upper end of the screen I often accidentally open Notification Center, cancelling my action. In Settings I found a Setting to disable the Control Panel in Apps, but I couldn’t find a similar Setting for the Notification Center.

How can I disable Notification Center in Apps in iOS?

I have iPhone 6s with iOS 13.1.3.

Comment: Which orientation do you play the game in ? In landscape fullscreen, both control centre and notification centre need to be pulled from the Centre, twice, using a temporary pullup(down) arrow.

Comment: That’s not true. I can pull down the Notification Center with just one swipe.

Comment: Yes, in landscape mode and full screen.

Comment: The game is mini metro, iOS 13.1.3 on iPhone 6s

Answer (score 1):

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3419084 has a person saying

> For apps which are running in full-screen (includes games, but also built in apps such as YouTube and Photos when they are in full-screen mode), the gesture which normally brings down the full notification center just brings down a little gray tab at the top middle of the screen. You can then slide that tab down, if you really want the notification center.

[iOS 7 Make Control Center hard to open like fullscreen mode while still showing status bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917541/ios-7-make-control-center-hard-to-open-like-fullscreen-mode-while-still-showing)

shows an example of control centre pullup gesture where a small arrow appears which forces us to swipe twice to get control centre in full screen apps. An answer says that

> The system will only show this tab when the status bar is hidden.

So most likely it is upto the developer to make appropriate changes to use this feature, instead of covering the screen in one go.

Comment: They are fairly old posts, but I have seen this behaviour in ios 12

Comment: Well, as I said, this is not the behavior I’m witnessing. I can pull the Notification Center down in just one swipe.

Comment: Anyway, what I’m looking for is a way to disable Notification Center entirely. Is that possible?

Comment: For the game:"most likely it is upto the developer to make appropriate changes"  For iOS: I never came across any such method.